# Problem detecting micro SDHC card

Tags: external-sd, micromax-a110

I recently purchased a Micromax A110 and I tried to use my old Sandisk micro SDHC card which is previously used on a Nokia 5233. The problem here is that the new Android phone is not detecting the micro SDHC card. Why won't it work?

Comment: Have you tried any other micro sd cards in the device to see if that works?

Comment: The existing micro sd card working fine on Nokia 5233 phone still. It had problem only with new android phone.

Comment: I asked if you have tried any other micro SD cards in the Android device.  It could be that the device is broken?

Comment: I Just tried with another micro sd card, it is working fine. Please notice the one worked is "micro sd" not the "micro sdhc". Is it problem with micro sd hc card?

Comment: Which **model**?  eg. *Micromax A110 Canvas 2* (or earlier model)  Which **Android** version?  What is the capacity of the SanDisk **micro-SDHC** card? .. and the ones which do work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the issue. The issue is that the memory card was **locked** by old Nokia phone. So I unlocked it and now it is working perfectly. Thanks for all your support.

Answer (score 1):

Not all equipment which uses SD cards can use SDHC cards.  It may be that your device doesn't support the sdhc card you are using.